# How to add Bootstrap Tool tips to a input field when its type=“file”

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I tried the following code,

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="fileField" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom"/>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
  });
</script>
```

after it executes I get this,

```
<input id="fileField" type="file" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" name="file" data-original-title="" title="">
```

Normally we add a title attribute to get a simple tool tip. But in the following example we get a simple tool tip without a title attribute. And it gets updated whenever we select a different file. I need these tool tips to be bootstrap tool tips and needs to be updated whenever I select a different file through "Choose File" button.
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_file

Comment: Did you try to read the Bootstrap documentation?

Comment: Yeah, tried that. But the problem is these file type input fields are not re-branded using Bootstrap FileStyle (http://markusslima.github.io/bootstrap-filestyle/). Im not allowed to change that now. Need to find a workaround to fix this. Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't matter if they are styled or not, it's just an `input` element. Follow the documentation and it will work.

Comment: @anshu, with `bootstrap-filestyle` it will work with simple `input` tags, just make sure you include the `bootstrap-filestyle` library as well in your script

Comment: May be the way I asked my question is bit confusing. So I changed it a little. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="fileField" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="No file selected"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
     $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); 
});
</script>
```

For Changing the Title:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
        $("fileField").change(function (){
          $("fileField").attr("title", "new Title Text");
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to change this, here is an example which i found on internet, it adds some `custom css` styling to the `file` upload tag with custom placeholder/tooltip message.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="browse-wrap">
  <div class="title">Choose a file to upload</div>
  <input type="file" name="upload" class="upload" title="Choose a file to upload">
</div>
<span class="upload-path"></span>
```

**CSS Code:**

```
input.upload {
    right:0;
    margin:0;
    bottom:0;
    padding:0;
    opacity:0;
    height:300px;
    outline:none;
    cursor:inherit;
    position:absolute;
    font-size:1000px !important;}
```

[Live Demo @ JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/dq4bb/186/)

*Note:The files property is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.*

For IE 9 or before version use below code to get the selected file name.

```
(this.value).split("\\")[2]
```

[IE specific demo @ JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/dq4bb/190/)

Comment: What I want to do is add a boots trap tool tip into the span tag(in your JSFiddle). Tool tip content should be the name of the chosen file name.

Comment: currently `upload-path` span does hold the name of the choosen file

Comment: Now the problem is this.files[0].name is not working on IE. But FF works fine. Is there a way around this? (The code I used to solve my problem is commented below as an answer) Thanks.

Comment: @Anshu: `files` are not supported on IE 9 or before, so its not working. anyway i have added a workaround for the same in my answer, check it

Comment: If i try to upload a file that's located in "C:\Users\test\Pictures\Training.jpg" I get "test" as the output in my system. But for some reason if I try to upload that same file in your JSFiddle it gives "Training.jpg". Any particular reason for that?

Comment: Also if I try to run that code in FF it shows as "undefined".

Comment: hmmm, well may be jsfiddle is ignoring some internal details, if you try to print the value of file input in jsfiddle you will get this output , `C:\fakepath\filename.ext` . fakepath is something added by jsfiddle. anyway you can get the last chunk of splitted filepath, check this http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/dq4bb/192/

Answer (score 0):

HTML Code

`<input type="file" name="file" id="fileField" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Tooltip on Bottom" />`

Javascript

`$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});`

Answer (score 0):

You mention the value in title

```
title="It'stool tips"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var fileInputField = document.getElementById('fileField'); 

fileInputField.onchange = function() {
  fileInputField.setAttribute("data-original-title", this.files[0].name);
}
```